# Textjoin not ignoring empty cell until enter is pressed a second time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I wrote a formula using `TEXTJOIN`. On my side it worked perfectly but when my colleagues tried to use my spreasheet, it just showed them the series of coma [image] as if the `ignore_empty` field of `TEXTJOIN` was set to `False`. But it's not, it is set to `True`.

When I tried to debug it, I just directly hit ctrl-shift-enter (it's embedded in an array formula) and the problem disappeared. Moreover if I modify the data selected by the formula (to make the value of the cell where there is my textjoin formula change) and then make a ctrl-z, the problem disappears too.

EDIT: Refreshing the sheet or using the calculate now function doesn't work. Also I have a cell next to the bugged one that contains the same formula and there is no problem on this one.

I'm using textjoin in an array formula like this : `TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((Table1[pass/fail]="FAIL")*(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[lvl]))),ROW(Table1[pass/fail]),""))`

---

My whole array formula looks like this:

`{=IF(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((Table1[pass/fail]="FAIL")*(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[lvl]))),ROW(Table1[pass/fail]),""))="",IF(B23="","Not run","No failure"),TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((Table1[pass/fail]="FAIL")*(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[lvl]))),ROW(Table1[pass/fail]),"")))}`

---

The problem is pretty random and I don't where it might come from so thank you in advance if you have encountered the problem before and managed to solve it.

Comment: Tell your colleagues to hit ctrl-shift-enter too. I had many surprising behaviors of Excel. Also, they might try hitting F9 (refresh).

Comment: @virolino well ideally I would rather like the sheet to work fine directly. This would just be a temporary solution... And also f9 or calculate now don't work so I will add that to the main question.

Comment: first, we need to understand what is wrong. Or, at least, find something that works. After that, we can come up with a proper solution ;)

Comment: Instead of `TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((Table1[pass/fail]="FAIL")*(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[lvl]))),ROW(Table1[pass/fail]),""))` use `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(Table1[pass/fail]="FAIL",IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[lvl])),ROW(Table1[pass/fail]),""),""))`, see if that solves it.

Comment: @virolino yes indeed, I'm trying to recreate the problem but it seems pretty random.

Comment: @JvdV the formula works I will come back here if the problem appears with it. But what makes you think the `and` (or `*`) is the problem?

Comment: I have no theory why really, just one thing I do when I encounter problems that seem bugs, try looking for other ways to achieve the same thing :). Maybe returning 1's and 0's doesn't seem to count as being `TRUE` or `FALSE` all the time? If this is valid theory than a simple check if the `*` equals 1 is also an option you could try: `TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((Table1[pass/fail]="FAIL")*(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[lvl])))=1,ROW(Table1[pass/fail]),""))`

Comment: @JvdV I see what you mean. And indeed `(TRUE*TRUE)` equals `1` but `AND(TRUE, TRUE)` equals `TRUE`. That could be the reason and I will change it, hopefully the problem comes from here.

Comment: @JackA No, you can't use `AND()` to check for both criteria to be true. It wouldn't return an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, just one true or false. Please notice I specifically DIDN'T use `AND` in my first suggestion!

Comment: @JvdV yes yes I know, I just wanted to compare with a logic operator